# proper escaping of regex in ABAP

Tags: regex, abap

I am trying to escape the following regex

```
(<t:Message>)[\s\S]*?(<\/t:Message>)
```

for using it in my ABAP source code.

All I got so far is the following:

```
(<t:Message>)[\\s\\S]\*?(<\/t:Message>)
```

But for any reason, it does not give the desired result.

Is there maybe any regex expert in here who could help me to escape this regex so that i can use it in ABAP? I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: Try `(?s)<t:Message>(.*?)</t:Message>`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That won't help in the ABAP environment, because `*?` is still not supported there...

Comment: @vwegert I referred to https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abenregular_expressions.htm It says ICU regex flavor is supported.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Not sure what you mean by "ICU" - bare fact is that using `*?` will raise an exception, unfortunately...

Comment: Are you trying to use RegEx to parse information out of an XML schema? Wouldn't it be better to use `CL_XML_DOCUMENT` which if I'm not mistaken is ABAP's implementation of DOM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two main issues with your expression, none of which has to do with escaping at all.

> The special characters \w, \u, \l, \d, and \s can also be specified
>   within sets [...]. Use of the special characters \W, \U, \L, \D, and
>   \S within sets is not permitted and raises the exception
>   CX_SY_INVALID_REGEX.

(quoted from the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenregex_syntax_signs.htm)) - so replace that with something else, like `.*`

> The regular expressions r{n,m}?, r*? and r+? are reserved for future
>   language enhancements (non-greedy behavior) and currently raise the
>   exception CX_SY_INVALID_REGEX.

(quoted from the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenregex_syntax_operators.htm)) - so don't use `*?`

`(<t:Message>).*(</t:Message>)` is at least syntactically correct - whether it does what you want is unclear since you do not specify what you need in the first place.

Comment: I did not see this documentation before, so i did not know that these parts of the regex are not supported.
According to your answer, the regex you provided works properly since I simply want to extract the message tags in a xml string.
Thank you very much.